# What was the nature of the dead universe in the Netflix Transformers: War for Cybertron Trilogy?

Tags: transformers

In the Netflix trilogy Transformers: War for Cybertron, the cast accidentally travel to a location referred to as "The Dead Universe". A lifeless region that has unusual - and often harmful - properties.

The dialog implies that the Dead Universe is another dimension or a universe apart from/outside of the cast's own universe.

Is the nature of the Dead Universe ever clarified in official source, for example a comic, novelization or video game, that is canonical to the Trilogy?

There is an identically named region in the Transformers comic from IDW that is a universe used as a power source by Shockwave, draining it of all life at the moment of its creation. Is this every confirmed to be the same Dead Universe, or a reimagining of it?